# How to use condition while creating new column in SQL view

Tags: sql, view, case

I have create a view in MY SQL server, where I need to use `CASE` condition in order to satisfy a requirement.

```
select 
  cast([SIR Per Occ] as float) * 1000000 as [SIR Per Occ],
  cast([SIR Agg] as float) * 1000000 as [SIR Agg],
  cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float) * 1000000 as [Per Occ Limit Between],
  cast((cast([SIR Per Occ] as float)) + (cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float)) as float) * 1000000 as [Policy Occ Attachment],
  cast((cast([SIR Agg] as float)) + (cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float)) as float) * 1000000 as [Policy Agg Attachment]
from IT.dbo.Policy_find
```

But in my task, if the `[Per Occ Limit Between]` is `NULL` values, then I need to assume it be as zero and the above code should be working as following logic :

```
Policy Occ Attachment = [SIR Per Occ]
Policy Agg Attachment = [SIR Agg]
```

How would I implement such scenario in the select clause without using `where` condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use CASE with your column definition instead of the column name ([CASE MSDN here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)).

EDIT (For SQL Server) : If you want to remove NULL values, you can use `ISNULL(YOUR_EXPRESSION, '')`

Comment: case when [Per Occ Limit Between] is null then  0 else cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float) * 1000000  end as [Per Occ Limit Between] .. This worked to a extent, but still it consider the 0 as string and doesn't adds up

Comment: you still can use a CAST over your case? `CAST( CASE WHEN exp THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, float)` It's a bit overkill but should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't decide if it's MY "SQL server" or "MY SQL" server.

But, actually, for this specific query it doesn't matter.

use `COALESCE`

```
select 
  cast([SIR Per Occ] as float) * 1000000 as [SIR Per Occ],
  cast([SIR Agg] as float) * 1000000 as [SIR Agg],
  cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float) * 1000000 as [Per Occ Limit Between],
  cast((cast([SIR Per Occ] as float)) + (cast(COALESCE([Per Occ Limit Between],0) as float)) as float) * 1000000 as [Policy Occ Attachment],
  cast((cast([SIR Agg] as float)) + (cast([Per Occ Limit Between] as float)) as float) * 1000000 as [Policy Agg Attachment]
from IT.dbo.Policy_find
```